# Как отследить изменения на сайте?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть сайт, отслеживающий некоторую информацию в реальном времени. Информация меняется - на сайте меняется цвет какого-либо элемента и/или текст в нем. Сайт чужой, на чем написан (php, asp.net или что-то ещё) - неизвестно. Фактически, все, что можно сделать - просмотреть html код средствами браузера.

Задача: написать приложение (десктопное на C# или веб-приложение на asp.net core), которое будет отслеживать изменения на сайте (например, для записи в журнал). Конкретнее, вопрос в том, как мое приложение может получить сигнал о том, что содержимое сайта изменилось. Реально ли это сделать? Если да - подскажите, пожалуйста, куда именно копать.

Comment: 1) Реально. 2) Не понятно что конкретно вам нужно - поэтому явно не отвечу. 3) Учитывая тематику поста - вам скорее всего нужны основы асп и основы c#. Так же не помешает js, Вашим клиентом является браузер. ASP не может напрямую управлять браузером, поэтому нужною инфу прийдётся по-таймеру подбирать подзапросами с асп-хоста.

Comment: Вы хотите отслеживать изменения на _чужом_ сайте? Тогда при чём здесь asp.net?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, все правильно. Просто asp.net - единственная веб-технология, с которой я хоть как-то знаком.

Comment: _Задача: написать приложение_ - вот и пишите "приложение". Любого типа (возьмите консольное).

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос: добавьте информацию (сайт не ваш, а чужой), добавьте метку языка (c#, vb.net, etc). Есть ли API у этого сайта?

Comment: Уберите метку asp.net-core - она бессмысленна в этом контексте. Добавьте метку, на каком языке собираетесь писать свое приложение.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что вы можете получить сигнал об изменении сайта, но вы можете его периодически опрашивать и сравнивать результаты предыдущего опроса с текущим и на основании этого делать вывод изменился ли он или нет.

Comment: По таймеру каждые n секунд/минут делаете запрос на сайт с помощью классов `HttpClient`, `WebClient` или `WebRequest`, парсите ответ, находите интересующую вас информацию. Но это не будет работать, если сайт динамический на javascript. Тогда, как вариант, можно использовать компонент `WebBrowser`, дожидаться в нём завершения загрузки, подписаться на событие изменения нужного элемента. Вероятно, для этого также можно использовать Selenium.

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз: метка asp.net-core бессмысленна. Эта технология для создания _собственных_ сайтов. Вам нужно работать с _чужим_ сайтом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Похоже, WebBrowser - как раз то, что нужно. Попробую. Спасибо!